# Getting a function to actually output HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seo

Have some JavaScript running that's dynamically building an array of images.

Here's the simplified version:

```
    var imgArray = new Array(
        "mainBG.jpg",
        "mainBG2.jpg",    
        "mainBG3.jpg",
        "mainBG4.jpg"
    );

    var img = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgArray.length);

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").ezBgResize({img : "/lib/img/bkgr/" + imgArray[img]});
    });

    function generateThumbs(){
         var t = document.getElementById("thumbs");
         var ret = '';

        for(i=0;i<imgArray.length;i++){

            var image = imgArray[i];

            ret += '<a href="#" onclick="changeBig(\''+image+'\')" /><img src="/lib/img/bkgr/'+image+'" alt="thumbnail image" width="77" height="44" /></a>';
        }      

        return ret;        
    };

    function changeBig(bg){
        $("body").ezBgResize({img : "/lib/img/bkgr/" + bg});
    }
```

Then in the page, it's being written out simply with:

```
 <div class="scrollable">   
    <div class="items" id="thumbs">
        <script>document.write(generateThumbs());</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is, when I view the source, it never outputs actual HTML. The source just shows that line. Is there a way to get that function to actually output HTML into the page-- partially for SEO, but also so some jQuery can interact with it
?

Comment: Webcrawlers rarely, if ever, execute Javascript. SEO would be useless on this, as the crawlers will never see your JS-generated content. That being said, try `document.getElementById('thumbs').innerHTML = generateThumbs()` instead.

Comment: "The source just shows that line" If you want to display the HTML directly, you will need to add it on the server-side, before deploying to the client.

Comment: Your `t` variable is redundant.

Comment: The source code just shows the original code send by the server, in all browser I know of the source code doesn't change when you modify the DOM using Javascript. Have you tried using the developer menu in Chrome/Safari or Firebug in Firefox?

Comment: Just to point out that document.getElementById('thumbs'); == $('#thumbs'); Please use jQuery only, for your own good of understanding the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
$(function(){
    $("#thumbs").html(generateThumbs());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When you view source all you see is the code returned to the browser from the webserver without any modifcations javascript has done to the dom. To have the code in the raw source you need to generate it on the server side.

To see the generated source with the javascript modifications you can use firebug in firefox or the built in developer tools in Chrome/Safari/IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `document.write` in the context of an HTML page. You should be doing something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     document.getElementById('thumbs').innerHTML = generateThumbs();
 </script>
```

Comment: While true, this is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Good point. If he wants the HTML to be rendered out initially, then he cant use javascript and needs to use some kind of server resources.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#thumbs').html(generateThumbs());
```